# ANSI C - Execute Process, Wait, Delete File

Tags: c, fork, execv

I am trying to execute LP to print a PDF document and wait for it to exit. After
it exists i am trying to delete the file with unlink();

However the wait finishes even before execv execute LP. I am not quite sure
how to handle this and why the wait isn't waiting till execv finishes.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

```
        if(fork())
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Executing command %s %s", "/usr/bin/lp", homedir);
            char *const parmList[] = {"/usr/bin/lp", homedir, (char *)0};
            execv("/usr/bin/lp", parmList );

        }else
        {
            int pid, status;
            fprintf(stderr, "Wait\n");
            pid = wait(&status);
            fprintf(stderr, "Finished waiting.\n");
            unlink(homedir);
        }
```

When executing the above code the ouput would look like this:

```
Wait
Finished waiting.
Executing command /usr/bin/lp /home/user/Docs/test.pdf
/usr/bin/lp: Error - unable to access "/home/user/Docs/test.pdf" - No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork()` returns zero in the child process, and a positive value in the parent process (assuming the fork succeeds), and `wait(...)` only makes sense in the parent process, so you need to swap the contents of your `if` and `else` blocks.